# use of Strichartz estimates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, strichartz-estimates

I have been learning(understanding) the [Strichartz estimates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strichartz_estimate#cite_note-1).

My naive Questions:

> (1) Can you give some ideas, how Strichartz estimates plays  role in solving nonlinear dispersive equations(e.g. non-linear Shrodinger) ? 
>   (2) Is this estimate helpful to get the local wellposedness results or global well posedness results ? 
>   (3)Can you motivates a bit why one should study this kind of estimates ?

Thanks,